# Expansion into convergent power series of two variables?

Tags: analysis, power-series

Suppose that $k(t,s)$ is real analytic with respect to both variables, then can we say that $k(t,s)$ can be expanded into power series of two variables in different neighborhood as
$$
k(t,s) = \sum k_{ij} (t-t_0)^i (s-s_0)^j?
$$
If not, what is the difference between them?